# Using a VBA function, How can I fix my loop to copy cell values to a new row based on a matching cell values in a column?

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to clean up some CSV report files that contain network asset information.

Column A contains PluginIDs for the various values. I want to copy the offset (0, x) and paste into a cell further up in the same column, based on matching host IPs in column B. Here is what I have so far.

```
Sub finalDataMove()

Dim LR As Long

LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LR
    If Range("A" & i).Value = "11936" Then
        Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 3).Copy
        **"Help me please!"**.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    End If

    If Range("A" & i).Value = "12053" Then
        Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 4).Copy
        **"Help me please!"**.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    End If

Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```

Comment: I don't understand. Where do you want to paste the copied value?

Comment: @Jack From the question ` and paste into a cell further up in the same column, based on matching host IPs in column B`, I understand as copy offset to first row wherecolumn B = current row column B, but I don't exactly know for sure either.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be written in a better way but i just tried to correct your code. i hope it will help you.

```
Sub finalDataMove()

Dim LR          As Long
Dim varCol      As Variant

LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LR
    If Range("A" & i).Value = "11936" Then
        varCol = Application.Match(Range("B" & i).Value, [B:B], 0)            
        Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 3).Copy
        Range("A" & varCol).Offset(0, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    End If

    If Range("A" & i).Value = "12053" Then
        varCol = Application.Match(Range("B" & i).Value, [B:B], 0)           
        Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 4).Copy
       Range("A" & varCol).Offset(0, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    End If

Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```